# nuget pacakge manager in visual studio 2015 doesn't restore javascript files

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, tfs

My development machine has .gitignore file, and none of the javascript files in the Scripts folder is checked in to our git repository on TFS.  Everything work fine in the folder on my machine where it was developed orginally.  When I clone it to another folder on my machine, or clone it from anther workstation, then compile, it compiled successfully. However, none of the javascript is restored during the compilation.  The package.config has the reference to the javascript and version.

There is also another problem that some javascript no longer exist in nuget.org.  How do I restore those files?  Thanks.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<packages>
  <package id="AjaxControlToolkit" version="16.1.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="AjaxMin" version="5.14.5506.26202" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="angularjs" version="1.5.8" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="AngularJS.Core" version="1.5.8" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="AngularJS.Resource" version="1.5.8" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.5.0.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.3.7" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="colorbox" version="1.4.29" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="elmah" version="1.2.2" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="elmah.corelibrary" version="1.2.2" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="FontAwesome" version="4.7.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="iTextSharp" version="5.5.10" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="jQuery.UI.Combined" version="1.12.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.15.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="json2" version="1.0.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.8.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="MySql.Data" version="6.9.9" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="9.0.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Nwic.Web.MainMenu" version="1.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="SlowCheetah" version="2.5.15" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Spin.js" version="2.3.2.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="VisualStudioGitIgnore" version="1.3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.6.0" targetFramework="net451" />
</packages>
```

Comment: If you don't want to depend on nuget.org you either [check in your packages ](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/01/29/nuget-package-restore-considered-harmful/) or run your own nuget server. Without seeing the output of the nuget restore command I cannot answer the first question though.

Comment: thank you. I have a Nuget local feed server with a nupkg with those javascript files.  I also add the NuGet local feed server to my VS2015 Package Sources in Tools/Options.  It still doesn't restore files from there either.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because your javascript files in Script folder isn’t checked into Git repository, when you clone the repository to another place, the javascript files won’t be included in that project. When compile your project, it only download/restore the javascript files to the “packages” folder and won’t add them to your project.

Run this command in Package Manager Console to reinstall your packages.

```
Update-Package –reinstall packageName
```